# TS - Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript

Why does the compiler says `TS2339: Property 'isDev' does not exist on type '{ isProd: boolean; }'.`?

```
const Env = {isProd: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"};
Env.isDev = !Env.isProd;
```

Can I not add undeclared members in TS?

Comment: Since you have declared a const, its type also gets defined as inferred from the assigned value.

Comment: ehh.. could you translate that to human language plz?

Comment: Because it's a constant variable, which means its value is never going to change after declaration, it also means the type for the variable will also be inferred from assigned value. In your case, type for `Env` variable is inferred as `{ isProd: boolean; }`. Since there is no property `isDev` in type `{ isProd: boolean; }`, hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. One option is to put anything your literal depends on in a variable first:

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

const Env = {
    isProd,
    isDev: !isProd,
};
```